# Which Javascript Framework for a data driven web application?

Tags: javascript, web, binding, frameworks, data-driven

I've been asked to design a web application which has multiple tiers.  It will have a **client** aspect (rendering information for the user), a **server** aspect (web api serving data) and a **database** behind it all.

I'm comfortable choosing the technology stack for the web api and database.  It will either be a choice of Microsoft Web Api with SQL backend OR nodeJS with MySQL.

For me the challenge (***and the prompt for this post***), is choosing the correct frameworks for the client side.

I've used AngularJS quite a few times and its fairly straightforward for me to go down this road again but the project in question will have a lifespan of 5 years and I'm worried that choosing Angular 1.x, having been out since 2009 and due to be replaced by Angular 2.0, which is completely different, is a bad investment.

I will most likely use bootstrap for the base css side.

So out of the plethora of frameworks out there - what would be the strongest for client side data driven web applications?

Some obvious choices being:

- Ember
- Backbone
- React
- Knockout
- Meteor
- Polymer
- Ractive
- Durandal
- Angular 2.0?

To name but a few!  Which is best and why?  I'm not looking to avail of server side capabilities of the likes of React.  Just data (read/write) from the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your list, I tried quite a few: angular (1), backbone, ractive. I had a look at a few others but didn't investigated them further.

**From *my* experience, Ractive was the winner. I still stick to it and am happy with it.**

My first experience was with backbone. It looked pretty simple and what I needed. However, when starting to do non-trivial stuff, I ended up pretty quickly in a dead end. My view and data sometimes went out-of-sync and I didn't know how I could perform some other stuff.

My second experience was Angular. With all the hype, I thought it must be great. But getting into it was hard. It's just ...complex. As soon as I wanted to build a non-trivial directive, I was like "wtf? wtf!". The second show-stopper was the debugging ability. At some point, everything broke and my debug console just threw a strange stack trace, giving me absolutely no clue what might be the problem. ...a long time after I discovered by chance that I had placed a `@` instead of a `#` or something like this. Also, one thing I disliked from the start is that it forces you to do everything angular-ly, which doesn't always play well with other libs.

My last experience is Ractive and I write production code with it since a year or so. I'm very happy with it. Sure, it's no silver bullet and has some quirks. But overall, it's a lib where you can quickly get started with, which can do a lot, and that doesn't get in your way. The mainainers are also supprisingly responsive.

**...but if you're experienced with angular, perhaps it's better to continue that way.**

That's my 2 cents.